# Creating NestJS Controllers and Modules in a NX Workspace

Tags: angular, nestjs, npx, nx-workspace

I am using the NX workspace's angular-nest boilerplate to get started with an App. Whenever I try to use the CLI or the NX extension to generate a controller/module etc, it gets placed in the wrong folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBR2n.png

For instance, if I generate a new module for nest, I would like it to be placed in `api/src` as that is where the Nest files are. But in my case if I use the command `nest generate module helloworld`, it gets placed in the `src/helloworld` folder outside of the `api/src` folder.

Is there a simpler way to make it so that my Nest components and modules etc are generated in the Nest folder and Angular components etc are in the Angular folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "NX console" extension ( which I see you already installed... )
[image]
[image: replace "data-store-api" with the name of the nest js project name]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the nx console in VSCode, you can also run the command `nx g @nrwl/nest:controller <controller-name> -p <project-name>`. [Check out the docs on the `@nrwl/nest` generators and their options](https://nx.dev/packages/nest/generators/controller)